# Symfony 1.4 with sfPropelORMPlugin and MySQL Replication

Tags: mysql, symfony1, replication, propel

I upgraded my symfony 1.4 project with the latest version of sfPropelORMPlugin and I created my runtime-conf.xml according to: http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/replication.html with the intend to write my sql to a master and read from the slaves.

I'm rebuilding my model with symfony propel:build-model and everything goes fine but both write/read SQL statements are sent to the master. I'm not sure I understand how propel is using runtime-conf.xml within the symfony framework.

Am I missing an extra step?